# How to load Powershell result into CSV or text file?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to load powershell result into a CSV or text file

First I need to get all disabled account using this:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly |FT Name
```

And it will return bunch of names that has been disabled. What should I do to load it into a CSV or TXT file?

Here is what I tried:

`Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly |FT Name | Export-CSV -Path C:\Users\hou\Downloads\Test.csv`

But the result is a bunch of things like '27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c', not the name that I want to.

What should I do to do this?

Comment: Do not use `FT Name` before `Export-Csv`. What property/properties do you want in the output CSV file?

Comment: Have you considered simply redirecting output, e.g., `Get-Process | ft >c:\foo.txt`?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I just need the names. What should I use? Thx

Comment: @Patrick87 I m noobie in PowerShell...don't know how to use them...could you please show me? Thx!

Comment: Replace `| Export-CSV -Path C:\Users\hou\Downloads\Test.csv` with `>C:\Users\hou\Downloads\Test.csv`. Does that work?

Comment: @Patrick87 Yes that works, but now that I have another problem. since I m gonna use this file to load into SQL table and my plan was to use SSIS to do that. Do you have any advise on how to do that?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Note that you can probably just connect to your SQL table from PowerShell and load the entries directly - but that's another story. You might ask a new question for SSIS, or add a tag and some more text to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | 
    Select Name | 
    Export-CSV -Path C:\Users\hou\Downloads\Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Then you'll have a CSV file with just the Names (including a header), that you can use as input to your DB's CSV import.

Format-Table transforms the objects into a stream of Formatting records which are intended for output but not for further processing. If you want to learn more about this see:

[PowerShell Basics: Formatting](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/powershell-basics-formatting)

[How PowerShell Formatting and Outputting REALLY works](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/30/how-powershell-formatting-and-outputting-really-works.aspx)

Comment: Probably will want a `-NoTypeInformation` on that `Export-Csv`.  I really don't understand why they made that the default instead of making a `-TypeInformation` flag that added the information.